# NodeJS: Diferença entre requisições (require)

Tags: node.js, requisição, require

Comecei a aprender NodeJS e notei que existem algumas maneiras de requirir um arquivo, duas delas são:

`const app = require('lib').app`

`const {app} = require('lib')`

Existe alguma diferença entre elas em relação ao desempenho ou ambas são iguais? Um amigo me disse ter visto em algum lugar (que não se lembra) que uma delas é mais pesada e pode influenciar no desempenho sempre que o arquivo for executado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ambas são iguais.

Usar `const {app} = require('lib')` é uma ferramenta nova que foi implementada na versão ES6, chamada [*Destructuring assignemt*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) e que não era possível antigamente. Ou seja, antes tinhas de fazer uma atribuição para cada propriedade.

No teu caso faz pouca diferênça mas se `require('lib')` exportar mais propriedades podes fazer todas numa só linha:

```
const {app, router, middleware} = require('lib')
```

Comment: Entendi! Obrigado.